# Limit results, from for loop within a function, to 10 results - Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, web-scraping, wikipedia

I have the below code which follows random Wikipedia links and prints title of articles. I am trying to limit it to 10 results and not infinite results, but I am finding it difficult to do. Can anybody help please?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

def scrape_wiki_article(article_url):
    response = requests.get(url=article_url,)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
    print(title.text)
    
    #Get all the links
    allLinks = soup.find(id="bodyContent").find_all("a")
    random.shuffle(allLinks)
    linkToScrape = 0
    
    for link in allLinks:
        #We are only interested in other wiki articles so look for /wiki/ prefix
        if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1: # -1 is returned by .find if substring is not found 
            continue
        
        #Use this link to scrape
        linkToScrape = link
        break
    
    scrape_wiki_article("https://en.wikipedia.org" + linkToScrape['href'])
 
scrape_wiki_article("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
```

Comment: Is `allinks` a list? If so, you could just use `for link in allinks[:10]: ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can start by filtering the all links list to only include links with the /wiki prefix. Once you do that, you can truncate the list by doing something like

```
allLinks = allLinks[:10]
```

This way you would search up to 10 Wiki links.